# Android - Can i get total running time?

Tags: android, linux

Please excuse my english.

In the Device Settings the system status just shows the recent uptime.
I want the total uptime from factory.

Comment: You like to know about total runtime of your application ?

Comment: abd shell or sdk etc.. just show me

Comment: with "i want the total uptime from factory" i feel like you want to get the time from system install. Maybe you mean boot?

Comment: yes, you right. OS boot time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, there is no direct way to get total Uptime from factory.

There is a kinda-workaround, where via `PackageManager` you can get the install time of and app using `getPackageInfo()` and `long firstInstallTime`. So, you can try to get the oldest app installed and take it from there.

Besides that - like I have said, there is no direct way.

*Based on answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081017/total-uptime-on-android-and-iphone)*

Answer (score 0):

```
adb shell commend in java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().

String cmd = "shellscript.sh";
String cmdreturn = "";
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
pr.waitFor();
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
     System.out.println(cmdreturn);
}
```

Refer [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) and [Debugging](https://source.android.com/devices/audio_debugging.html)